# compare slopes of two line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let us consider  following problem:

In the $xy$-plane, the point $(1, 2)$ is on line $j$, and the point $(2, 1)$ is on line $k$. Each of the lines has a positive slope.

we should compare slopes of both line to each other,i think that answer is $D$ ,because we may have such kind of two line

$y=x+1$

and

$y=x-1$

so we see that their slopes are equal,but we may have also

$y=2*x$ or slope $2$ and  $y=1/2*x$ or slope $1/2$,so i think that there is not enough information to compare slopes of lines,am i correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have enough information to tell the equation of the lines $j$ and $k$. With just one point on the lines, you have one degree of freedom when defining the lines, so you are right to say that there is insufficient information to conclude anything about the gradients of the lines.